# Construir vistas UserControl "dinamicamente"

Tags: c#, xaml

Intento crear un determinado numero de vistas en funcion de un valor y añadirlos a la vista principal, en un StackPanel;

```
    private void ConstruirFilas(int numFilas)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < numFilas; i++)
        {
            StackConfiguracion.Children.Add(new ConfigNivel(i));
        }
    }
```

Si lo hago de esta manera, las vistas se crean pero no se como acceder a las propiedades o métodos de esos objetos que se han creado dentro del `for` ya que se crean "al vuelo".
¿Podria de alguna manera acceder a ellos?

Por otra parte, si creo un array de objetos `ConfigNivel` y luego intento pasárselos en el for me da un error en tiempo de ejecución alertándome de que no puedo pasar valores nulos, el código es este;

```
    private void ConstruirFilas(int numFilas)
    {
        ConfigNivel[] aaa = new ConfigNivel[8];

        for (int i = 1; i < numFilas; i++)
        {
            StackConfiguracion.Children.Add(aaa[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: La segunda version, justamente, tiene todos valores nulos.. creaste el vector pero no le asignaste valores a cada posicion. La primera version, se puede recorrer el arbol de objetos usando StackConfiguracion.Childs (te vas a volver loco suelen tener 1000 hijos). que estas buscando? a mi siempre me gusta mas la idea de tener un vector direccionado (como la segunda version)

Comment: Necesito llamar al mismo metodo (de cada objeto) para sumarlos todos y sacar un resultado total (en funcion de los objetos que haya creado).
¿Que metodo dices que es? No encuentro nada referente childs dentro del StackConfiguracion:
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes acceder a los `Children`de `StackConfiguration` directamente. Usando tu ejemplo, para crearles utilizas este código:

```
for (int i = 1; i < numFilas; i++)
{
    StackConfiguracion.Children.Add(new ConfigNivel(i));
}
```

Luego, para acceder a ellos, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
var vistas = StackConfiguracion.Children.OfType<ConfigNivel>();
```

Esto devuelve un `IEnumerable<ConfigNivel>`, que luego puedes recorrer con un `foreach` por ejemplo:

```
foreach (var vista in vistas)
{
     //en vista tienes cada una de las vistas que añadiste con anterioridad
     // puedes llamar al método de cada una
     vista.tuMetodo();
}
```

Comment: Eso es exactamente lo que quería, un diez!!